Delete image from form after invalidated
I made a custom hook_alter_form to invalidate and delete a image if invalid.
php code in the .module file
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter() to add custom validation for image ratio.
 */
function scouts_module_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  // Specify the form IDs where you want to replace the validation.
  $target_form_ids = [
    'node_boemerang_form',
    // Add more form IDs as needed.
  ];

  // dpm($form_id); // print the form id at the top of the page to find the correct form id.

  // Check if the current form ID is one of the target form IDs.
  if (in_array($form_id, $target_form_ids)) {
    // Replace the file_validate_image_resolution validation function.
    $form['#validate'][] = 'force_aspect_ratio';
  }
}

/**
 * Custom validation handler to enforce image ratio.
 */
function force_aspect_ratio($form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $image_field = $form_state->getValue('field_afbeelding');

  if (!empty($image_field)) {
    // Load the file entity.
    $file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($image_field[0]['fids'][0]);
    if ($file) {
      // Get the image properties.
      $image_info = getimagesize($file->getFileUri());
      $width = $image_info[0];
      $height = $image_info[1];
      $aspect_ratio = $width / $height;

      if ($aspect_ratio < 1) {
        $form_state->setErrorByName('field_afbeelding', t('Verticale foto\'s zijn lelijk, upload een horizontale.'));
        
        $file->delete();
        $form_state->setValue('field_afbeelding', []);
      }
    }
  }
}

The invalidation works but not the deletion:

I want it to go back to:

